# Programmatically Set Default Text Editor

Tags: 7, hooks, forms, wysiwyg

I have a customized module that requires tinyMCE as a library.

[image]

After module installation, I still have to set my text editor in the image above. It was found in the `admin/config/content/wysiwyg`.

How will I programatically set tinyMCE as a default text editor right after module installation?

Answer (score 2):

Below code is used in wysiwyg_profile_form_submit() at [wysiwyg.admin.inc](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/wysiwyg/tree/wysiwyg.admin.inc?h=7.x-2.2). You can make use of it.

```php
// Insert new profile data.
db_merge('wysiwyg')
  ->key(array('format' => $format))
  ->fields(array(
    'editor' => $editor,
    'settings' => serialize($values),
  ))
  ->execute();
wysiwyg_profile_cache_clear();
```

Another approach is using drupal_form_submit() to submit its settings form programmatically. But it would be more compliated.

Also, before settings the profile, you need to check if tinymce is existing.

```php
if (wysiwyg_get_editor('tinymce')) {

  // set profile.

}
```

Comment: Where will I get the value for $values?

Comment: The `$values` is from `$form_state['values']` ([source](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/wysiwyg/tree/wysiwyg.admin.inc?h=7.x-2.2#n325)). It is quite hard to build the array by yourself. You can save the settings first, then copy the value on `settings` column in table `wysiwyg`, then use unserialize tool to convert the string into array.